# Variable declaration in Java with conditional blocks

Tags: java

In both the cases below , I don't need the name outside the conditional block. Which of these approaches is better and why?

**Approach 1**

```
String name = null
if(){
name = "hello";
} else {
name = "carlo"
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
  if(){
    String name = "hello";
    } else {
    String name = "carlo"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the more likely event that you want to use the value of name that you've set after the `else` block ends, the first approach is better, because the second will not compile; the variables `name` will not be visible outside the `if`/`else` block.

In the less likely event you are intending to treat them as separate variables and handle them separately, Approach 2 is superior as it would make the scope of each variable more local and thus make your code more modular.

UPDATE: having changed the question, it is clear that you want the second ("less likely") situation. So Approach 2 is, in your case, superior.

Comment: Thanks David , this helps.